# Преобразовать объект в массив массивов

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Створи функцію `getRobotSchema`, яка приймає об'єкт `robot` і повертає набір ключів і типи значень, які в них мають зберігатися. Результат має виглядати ось так: `[[key, type], [key, type]...]`

Приклад:

```
  const robot = {
    version: 16,
    name: 'Cleaner 3000',
    coords: [345, 12],
  };

  getRobotSchema(robot) === [['version', 'number'], ['name', 'string'], ['coords', 'object']]
```

Пока дорешала вот до этого момента, но он выводит в консоль только одно последнее значение массива, а остальные два выводит как `null`

```
function getRobotSchema(robot) {
   const robotLength = Object.keys(robot).length;
   const typeRobot = Array(robotLength);

  //console.log(typeRobot.length);

  for (const i = 0; i < typeRobot.length; i++) {
    for (const key in robot) {
      console.log(key);
      console.log(typeof robot[key]);
      typeRobot[i] = [key, typeof robot[key]];
    }

     return typeRobot;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать все гораздо проще, а именно использовать метод `Object.entries`, который вернет уже почти нужный результат.

То что будет после `Object.entries(robot)` :

```
[['version', 16], ['name', "Cleaner 3000"], ['coords', [345, 12]]]
```

Используем `map` чтобы преобразовать получившийся массив:

1. Всего будет три итерации в `map`, так как в массиве три элемента(элементы перебираемого массива в данном случае тоже массивы)
2. Если использовать map таким образом: `entries.map(arr => )`, то на каждой итерации в `arr` будет последовательно лежать следующие массивы

   ```
   1-я итерация: ['version', 16]

   2-я итерация: ['name', "Cleaner 3000"]

   3-я итерация: ['coords', [345, 12]]
   ```
3. Но чтобы добраться до внутренностей массива используем деструктуризацию: `([key,value])`. Теперь `map` выглядит таким образом `entries.map(([key,value]) =>` и теперь на каждой итерации

в `key` будет:

```
  1-я итерация: 'version'

  2-я итерация: 'name'

  3-я итерация: 'coords'
```

в `value`:

```
  1-я итерация: 16

  2-я итерация: "Cleaner 3000"

  3-я итерация: [345, 12]
```

Останется только изменить значения `value` на `typeof(value)`, а `key` оставить без изменений, поэтому из `map` возвращаем следующий массив `[key, typeof(value)]`

```js
function getRobotSchema(robot) {
    const entries = Object.entries(robot)
    return entries.map(([key,value]) => [key, typeof(value)])
}

const robot = {
  version: 16,
  name: 'Cleaner 3000',
  coords: [345, 12],
}

console.log(getRobotSchema(robot))
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, а можно ли как-то продолжить моё решение?

Comment: @oaleksandrovva добавил описание к ответу, я думаю что в данном случае лучше использовать `Object.entries`, так как он вернет уже почти нужный результат, а не `Object.keys`

Comment: Спасибо, а можно как-то эту строчку подробнее расписать чтобы я в ней разобралась return entries.map(([key,value]) => [key, typeof(value)]); То мне одного ответа недостаточно нужно понять как этот весь процесс происходит

Comment: @oaleksandrovva добавил описание